# Comparing large databases

Tags: python, mysql, database

Suppose that we have two tables, table A and table B, and suppose that A and B are both very large: table A consists of 500000 rows and 20 columns and table B consist of 1000000 rows and and 20 columns. Suppose furthermore that there is no unique index available for the rows.

**Question:** What is the fastest way to check the overlap between the two tables? Should I use some form of hashing? Would it be doable to compare the tables within a couple of minutes and if not; how long *would* it take? I guess that just comparing each row of A with each row of B would take a lot of computing time?

Thanks!

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: I think this question is better suited to https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the fastest solution would be to create an index on one of the tables on some field that is well distributed, i.e. where there would be few cases of two records having the same value in that field. Then you could do a fast search with a join on that field.

Creating the index and then running the comparison will almost certainly be faster than running a comparison without an index.

Exactly how long it will take will depend on the size of the fields, how fast your server is, etc. But with a decent index, "a few minutes" is not an unreasonable expectation.

If there's some reason why you don't want an index, then delete it when you're done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How long do you think it would take on a macbook?:)

Comment: I don't know. It would be less work to try it and see than to try to build a mathematical model to estimate. And way more reliable: an ounce of experiment is worth a pound of theory. If you don't have the fully populated tables, I'd suggest creating dummy data, write a short program or query to just fill a table with "a", "b", "c", etc, or whatever is appropriate for the data types.

Comment: I asked another question related to this question. Since you had such an elegant solution for this problem, would you mind looking at that question as well?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a sql table and simply compare the values using the following command. This command will work great for tables with less than a million rows.

```
SELECT * FROM a INTERSECT SELECT * FROM b;
```